# Changing shape of scroll bar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change the shape of the scroll bar in my page. Right now it is the common rectangle shaped one but i want it to be kind of an oval shape - rounded at both top and bottom of the rectangle.

How Can i achieve this through CSS? Or is this not possible at all.
I am looking for supporting this in IE10.
This is my css for the scroll bar that I have.

```
.scrollbar-vertical
{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 17px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color:#999;
    scrollbar-arrow-color:white;
    scrollbar-base-color:white;
    scrollbar-face-color:#999;
    border-radius:5px 5px;

}
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2012/07/11/customize-scrollbar-via-css/

Comment: Not a cross-browser solution, so I won't leave it as an answer, but you could do something like this: [Demo @ Codepen](http://codepen.io/brbcoding/full/xhDbd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this page for a good starting point http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars. These only work for browsers that use webkit unfortunately.

To get the rounded oval shape scrollbars you can do something like below:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #D62929;
}
```

Not tested, you can use a jQuery custom scrollbar as seen on this page: http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Comment: This code is just for Chrome and Safari, There is any similar code for Mozilla and Opera and IE ?